# Computing the Convex Hull of two non intersecting polygon in scipy

Tags: convex-hull

Is there any scipy method that computes the Convex hull of two non intersecting polygon? I have 2 set of points P1 and P2 and their convex hulls CH(P1) and CH(P2), where the hulls are non intersecting. I want to find the Convex hull of union of points in P1 and P2. Is there any build in method in scipy?

Comment: Coding questions and questions about specific programming libraries or languages are off-topic on CS.SE, but can be asked on Stack Overflow.  See our [help/on-topic].  CS.SE is for questions about concepts, algorithms, and science.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for Scipy's convex hull implementation can be found [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html). Simply concatenate the two arrays of points to obtain their union. Feed this set to the convex hull algorithm.

Every point in each polygon lies within the convex hull of its polygon. In turn, both polygons have their convex hull contained entirely inside the larger convex hull. So, every point in each polygon lies within the larger convex hull, meaning it is also valid for the complete union of polygon points.

Comment: But when one feeds the union of points to the method, the complexity is nlogn, whereas the convex hull of the union can be determined in linear time.

Comment: You are correct that a [linear algorithm](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/books/compgeom.html) exists to solve your problem. However, this is a very specific optimization not implemented in SciPy. Do you really need to solve the problem linearly? Unless you have massive sets of points, it won't be much faster.

Comment: I need it for one of my assignments. This is not the main part of the assignment. I think I can live with it. It just does not make the algorithm nlogn .

Comment: The link in my previous comment is to a book that has an implementation you could use, but it's not in Python.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. I was thinking if there is a short cut method for doing it. Thanks anyway.